# How to overcome the "The member's SID could not be resolved" error when checking if user is a member of group?

Tags: c#, active-directory

We have a process that requires to check whether a particular user is a member of local Administrators group.

The code that checks that looks like the following:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, null))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sUserName);
    if (user != null)
    {
         SecurityIdentifier adminsGroupSID = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
         GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, adminsGroupSID.Value);
         if (group != null)
         {
             if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
                 return 0;
         }
    }
}
```

When the group has accounts (e.g. domain accounts) that were removed, we're getting a PrincipalOperationException and a message "An error (1332) occurred while enumerating the group membership.  The member's SID could not be resolved."

Is there any way to overcome this without:
a) Removing manually the orphaned SIDs from the group
b) Not ignoring it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is based heavily on my finding at http://www.seirer.net/blog/2013/9/12/how-to-deal-with-localized-or-renamed-administrators-in-net written by Michael Seirer.  He was attempting to get the SID of the local Admin account, while all we need are the names in that group.  The reason for the error "The member's SID could not be resolved." is because there are accounts that are no longer recognized in Active Directory - likely relics that point to deleted user accounts.  You can either do what Microsoft says and just delete them and hope your app never crashes again (though it will, the next time an account is deleted that is sitting in that Administrators group), or solve it permanently with this code I slightly modified from Mike.

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ConvertSidToStringSid(IntPtr pSid, out string strSid);

private static string GetTextualSID(DirectoryEntry objGroup)
{
    string sSID = string.Empty;
    byte[] SID = objGroup.Properties["objectSID"].Value as byte[];
    IntPtr sidPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SID.Length);
    sSID = "";
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(SID, 0, sidPtr, SID.Length);
    ConvertSidToStringSid((IntPtr)sidPtr, out sSID);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sidPtr);
    return sSID; 
}


public static List<string> GetLocalAdministratorsNames()
{
    List<string> admins = new List<string>();
    DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
    string adminsSID = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null).ToString();

    string localizedAdmin = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(adminsSID).Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();

    localizedAdmin = localizedAdmin.Replace(@"BUILTIN\", "");

    DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find(localizedAdmin, "group");
    object adminmembers = admGroup.Invoke("members", null);

    DirectoryEntry userGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("users", "group");
    object usermembers = userGroup.Invoke("members", null);

    //Retrieve each user name.
    foreach (object groupMember in (IEnumerable)adminmembers)
    {
        DirectoryEntry member = new DirectoryEntry(groupMember);

        string sidAsText = GetTextualSID(member);
        admins.Add(member.Name);            
    }
    return admins;
}
```

It will return a `List<string>` of members of the local Administrators group on the local machine.  You can even alter `Environment.MachineName` to be any computer name in your domain, if you don't want the local machine.

Then you can iterate the list to see if they're in it:

```
private static bool isAdmin(string user)
{
    //string user = @"DOMAIN\doej";
    user = user.Split(@'\')[1];

    List<string> admins = GetLocalAdministratorsNames();
    foreach (string s in admins)
    {
        if (s == user)
            return true; // admin found
    }
    return false;  // not an admin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost a decade later and even in .NET 4.x and 5.x, this is still a problem. One other way of working around this error is to basically deconstruct the code behind the `foreach` statement and make your own list to search. You need to get the Enumerator, then call MoveNext in a Try/Catch. I was originally afraid it would **not** move to the next one if it threw the exception, but it does, so this works.  It's not pretty, but I have tested it and it works for me.

```cs
PrincipalContext principalContext;
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal;
UserPrincipal userPrincipal;
bool hasItem;

// `members` is the new list that can be searched without errors.
List<Principal> members = new List<Principal>();

using (principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    SecurityIdentifier adminsGroupSID = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
    using (groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Sid, adminsGroupSID.Value))
    {
        /*
         * We will get our Enumerator. At this point, we are positioned before 
         * the current item, so we have to call MoveNext to get a valid Current
         */
        var e = groupPrincipal.Members.GetEnumerator();
        hasItem = false;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                /*
                 * Try and move next. If it failes, it will be caught by the catch
                 * and ignored. At which point, we can try and call MoveNext again
                 * and get to the next one.
                 */
                hasItem = e.MoveNext();
                if (hasItem)
                {
                    members.Add(e.Current);
                }
            }
            catch (PrincipalOperationException)
            {
                // We don't care about doing anything here--we just want to ignore the error
            }
        } while (hasItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: kudos
So far this is the only solution if you need to enumerate local group members in domain where domain object was removed. In addition it is good to add second exception 
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) which occurs if you enumerate local group members right after  it's domain user/group member was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the error is to go other way around.
Instead of checking if an user is member of a group, retrieve first all the groups and check the list for your target group. One drawback: is slower....

```
var groups = UserPrincipal.Current.GetAuthorizationGroups();
var found = groups.FirstOrDefault(principal => principal.Name == "Administrators");
var isMemberOfAdminGroup = found != null;
```

Thanks [arus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497423/arus) for your help :)

Comment: This won't help if you want to check the local Administrators group on your machine.  This queries the Administrators group in AD - just so we're clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool UserHasLocalAdminPrivledges(this UserPrincipal up)
{
   SecurityIdentifier id = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
   return up.GetAuthorizationGroups().Any(g => g.Sid == id)
}
```

Comment: `GetAuthorizationGroups()` goes against AD, not the local computer, or another remote computer. it is AD-centric and nothing to do with local groups. That said, the use of the builtin group's SID to look to see if that group is in the AD Administrator's group is a bit of an odd way to do it, but might work. I didn't test this, but it's a bit of going around the barn first instead just going through the door.

Answer (score -1):

There are three possibile solutions (all untested, using the last myself for all sort of domain groups):
1) Load the group and enumerate the members yourself
2) Load the underlying object of the group and use properties["Members"], which is a list of SIDs.
3) Use GetAuthorizationGroups() of the user (which will also use your non-direct groups, Service-Account has to be member of "Windows Authorization Group" and "PreWindows 2000 Comaptible...." eventually) and use the group list to lookup your Admin group.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will check what can be done. Also, probably you would recommend some similar solution for adding user to a group? Same issues when we do group.Members.Add(user).

Comment: Well, the underlying object will always work, but is not as comfortable as the AccountManagement-Namespace. But it seems the AccountManagement-Namespace has some flaws, which need workarounds. You could also write a repair-function for the groups...

Comment: @TGlatzer: How can I Enumerate? I am getting error while looping through it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913995/while-trying-to-resolve-a-cross-store-reference-the-sid-of-the-target-principal

Comment: 1.  Can't enumerate.  As shown by Rajesh, it gives an exception - which Microsoft doesn't even care about fixing because they say the workaround is to remove the dead accounts.  2.  `GetUnderlyingObject()` didn't provide me any values when loading `DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)groupPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject()`.  3.  `GetAuthorizationGroups()` goes against AD, not the local computer, or another remote computer.  it is AD-centric and nothing to do with local groups.