# While trying to resolve a cross-store reference, the SID of the target principal could not be resolved. The error code is 1332

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, active-directory-group

While fetching users from group, giving exception message as "While trying to resolve a cross-store reference, the SID of the target principal could not be resolved.  The error code is 1332."

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adUserName))
        {
            ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, adUserName, adPassword);
        }
        else
        {
            ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
        }
        var groupNames = commaSeparatedGroupNames.Split(',');
        IEnumerable<Principal> users = null;
        foreach (var groupName in groupNames)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName))
            {
                var userGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, groupName.Trim());
                if (userGroup == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Active Directory Group Not Found :: " + groupName);

                var usersInGroup = userGroup.GetMembers();

                if (users == null)
                {
                    users = usersInGroup;
                }
                else
                {
                    users = users.Union(usersInGroup);
                }
            }
        }

        return users;
```

When doing

```
foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
```

I am getting the error.
Any suggestions i can check for this error or skip this member from list during looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered this same problem yesterday, and this is the best answer I found at this [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27054184/Foreign-Security-Principals-that-have-been-deleted-in-trusted-domain.html):

```
IEnumerator<Principal> enumerator = members.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    try
    {
        Principal member = enumerator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\r\n\t{1}\r\n\t{2}",member.ToString(),member.Guid,member.DistinguishedName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is how you would iterate the IEnumerable collection 'manually'.  It gives you a chance to attempt getting the Principal and to catch the exception if it's an undefined SID or some other issue.

Comment: I did not want to iterate through each member as there might be many members. But the Enumerator should do it... I did it long back, so not sure this will work though.

Comment: In fact, the exception is thrown on the `MoveNext()` method. You have to move the `try..catch` block outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Sandra's solution is almost right, but the exception is thrown on the `MoveNext()` method, so if you place your `try..catch` block inside it, it won't work.

```
var enumerator = members.GetEnumerator();

var moveNext = true;

while (moveNext)
{
    try
    {
        moveNext = enumerator.MoveNext();

        if (moveNext)
        {
            Principal member = enumerator.Current;
        
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\r\n\t{1}\r\n\t{2}", member, member.Guid, member.DistinguishedName);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is tied to the return type of `group.GetMembers()`, which isn't neccessarily a `UserPrincipal` but a `Principal`.

So you might want to check, if the `Principal` is a `UserPrincipal` or a `GroupPrincipal`.

```
foreach(var principal in groupMembers)
```

would be a better choice in your case.

Comment: that too gives me the error. I just want to skip this row, any idea how it can be done any way

Comment: It comes out of the loop and groupMembers is IEnumerable, so dont know how to get rid of that item. And also once i get the exception on groupMembers, i cant do anything on it, it throws the exception.

Comment: how about something like `groupMembers.ToArray()` or even `groupMembers.OfType<UserPrincipal>().ToList()`?